# Get Vector of keys from TreeMap [keySet()]

Tags: java, tree, xpages

I am creating a Tree structure in a CacheBean, like so:

```
private TreeMap<String,Object> locations = new TreeMap<String,Object>();
```

So one bit of data would look like this:

```
ThisKey=[Chris,Jim,Rick,David]
```

I want to have users pick from a list of the keys. But if I bind the TreeMap directly to the field I get a this error:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: java.util.TreeMap incompatible with java.util.List
```

How can I get a vector of the keys to use as a picklist? I have tried to use

```
CacheBean.treeMap.keySet();
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: `new ArrayList(CacheBean.treeMap.keySet());` would give you a list...

Comment: Why do you want a list instead of the set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a `Vector` it is

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<>(CacheBean.treeMap.keySet());
```

**Edit**

But as [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) states:

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to
>   implement the List interface, making it a member of the Java
>   Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations,
>   Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed,
>   it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector.

You probably should use `ArrayList` and there it works the same, as with almost any Java `Collection` class.

Comment: Don't use `java.util.Vector`. It's been obsolete since 1998. How long have you been programming with Java?

Comment: Lew - Sadly Vectors are still heavily used in some pieces of IBM API technology.    We don't have a choice we need to use them some things.

Comment: Lew, David is correct. And in fact I have not been programming in Java for very long. Learning as I go, and unfortunately I have to be limited by what IBM does.